# I've got some problems on Ubuntu 13.04, any help!

Tags: laptop, power-management, battery, overheating

1. I can't set script (or by any other way through terminal) for making thresholds for battery charging, Also I know that Lenovo users provided `tp_smapi` kernel module which make this issue not considered as an unsolvable problem unless for Dell users, Also i tried this http://www.serkey.com/ubuntu-thinkpad-battery-threshold-tool-easy-script-bebzu4.html but it is not working for me, any solutions for controlling thresholds charging by any way?
2. I think my laptop temperature getting high with no reason which makes it produces extra heat even if the laptop is in its idle state, considering also my trying to use `Jupiter` but it have not effect on the heat also in its power saving plan, so is there a way to make power plan to save the battery power?

Answer (score 1):

Try the TLP power management application. Lower power consumption should reduce heat. I've been using it on my Acer Aspire laptop and it has drastically lengthened life of the battery. Run these commands to install it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw
```

Then reboot your computer or run `sudo tlp start`

If you're running on a Thinkpad, you must also install these:

```
sudo apt-get install tp-smapi-dkms acpi-call-tools
```

Hope this tool helps you!

Comment: TLP doesn't have any good approach affects my Laptop temperature, also what about battery charging thresholds ?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with thresholds, but it looks like tp-smapi allows you to alter them. Check out [this wiki page](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Tp_smapi).